# Form values to create own URL with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form that is a simple dropdown menu that users can select an name and the affiliate code matched to it be used in the url but php changes the periods to underscores, so I was wondering if there was a roundabout way of doing it with javascript?

```
<form>
<div>
<label for="organisation">Please select:
 </label>
<select name="quote/results.php?product=product_here&ac=group&username" method="get">
<option value="111111111">Number One</option>
<option value="222222222">Number Two</option>
<option value="333333333">Number Three</option>
<option value="444444444">Number Four</option>
 </select>
 <button>Quote </button>
 </form>
```

After the username in the URL, that's where I want the number code to go which I had working in php but the results.php turned into results_php which obviously came back as an error.

Are there any possible ways to go around this?

Comment: The name attribute is for identifying the select element.  You shouldn't really be using it the way you are.  Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do, without telling us how you think it should be done?

Comment: I'm trying to take the option value from the form that the user will select and add it on to the end of the url in the select name section so they'll all be redirected to the same page just with the value part different as that will work as an affiliate code

Comment: No, you do not want it in the select name.  See the answer by @Swellar below - I think that's probably what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<form action="quote/results.php" method="GET">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="product_here"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ac" value="group"/>
        <label for="organisation">Please select:</label>
        <select name="username">
            <option value="111111111">Number One</option>
            <option value="222222222">Number Two</option>
            <option value="333333333">Number Three</option>
            <option value="444444444">Number Four</option>
         </select>
         <button type="submit">Quote</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Put the `url` in the `action` attribute of the form instead, then use hidden inputs for the `product` and `ac`, so that they are included in the `url` after submitting. And add `type="submit"` in the buton